# how might I disable a div when the data inside it reaches 0 possibly using an if else?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a snippet of javascript that displays the amount of sessions available for an event

```
for ( var j in data.events[i].sessions ) {
                    first_session_id = !first_session_id ? data.events[i].sessions[j].id : first_session_id;
                    session_html += 
                        '<li id="session_row_'+ data.events[i].sessions[j].id +'">'+ data.events[i].sessions[j].time+
                        '<div class="right">'+ data.events[i].sessions[j].available +' sessions remaining</div></li>';
                }
```

at the moment when the sessions become empty or are all booked the value -1 is displayed. What I would like to do is add an if else statement that basically disables or blacks out the .right when we get to 0?

Can anyone advise me on how this might be done?

Regards
Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you already wrote the pseudocode:

```
if (data.events[i].sessions[j].available===0) { $('div.right').hide(); }
```

Comment: thanks @mblase75, ive updated my code above, how does this if fit in?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery (which you should :0) then http://api.jquery.com/hide/ will do the trick, and show to revert.

If jQuery is not an option, you have to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("class", "hide");
```

And then in your CSS do a `.hide { display: none;}` 
You then also have to cater for showing this again (I think). So on anything else than 0, do the same as above, but use e.g. `.show { display:block; }`